# UitextField and UIWebView interaction?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I put some text into the `textField` like: `"Peter.at"`, and the `UIwebview` shows all correct (Mag. pharm. Peter MÜLLER)!

The Problem is when I type in the `UItextField`: "Püter.at", the `UIwebView` does nothing!

What is wrong? I think it is the "ü" but I don't know how to fix it!

Comment: (Mag. pharm. Peter MÜLLER) = http://Peter.at

Comment: Hi Gert... your question is somewhat confusing.  Do you have a web page (being displayed in the UIWebView) with a text field inside it (from HTML, not a UITextField)?  Or do you have a separate text field (which can be a UITextField) trying to load a UIWebView?  I think I know the answer you want, but please clarify your question first.  Thanks.

Comment: i have a separate text field!

Comment: Please modify your original question to show a bit of code as to how you are accessing the string from the UITextField.  Thanks!

Comment: `NSString *preURL = @"http://www. ";
 NSString *middleURL = @".at";

 [uiwebnamesearch loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",preURL ,1.text,middleURL]]]];
[uiwebnamesearch reloadInputViews];`

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  I see what the problem is.

Your code should look like this:

```
NSString *preURL = @"";
NSString *middleURL = @".at"; 
NSString *fullURLString = 
    [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",preURL,1.text,middleURL] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL * preparedURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:fullURLString];

[uiwebnamesearch loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: preparedURL]]; 

[uiwebnamesearch reloadInputViews];
```

The important change here is that you are "percent escaping" the string, to make it possible to use in a URL.

Here is the documentation for that [[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a) method.

Comment: If any answer on StackOverflow works for you, don't forget to 'accept' it (it helps to motivate people to want to answer questions).  :-)